# Ending an application(game) and exit or and start a new one

Tags: javafx-8

So how does one end an application/game on a button click and exit as if the window red close symbol (X) has been clicked on or better still 
how does one end the current application and without closing the whole window / stage starts a new one ?
so for example we have something like

```
public class Main extends Application
{   
    public Scene scene ;
    private parent createContent()
    {
      // root pane, nodes and everything is here
      //which makes up the game
      //return root;
    }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) 
  {
    scene = new Scene(createContent());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();   
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);   }
}
```

So at the end of the current game, the user should be giving the option to start a new game or to exit the application completely by clicking on buttons. If he should click on exit game then the game should close as if he has pressed on the window red x close symbol. 
If the user should click on start a new game, then the prefered behavior will be for method
    private parent createContent()
to start all over again, but of course all stages and nodes created in the previous calls of createContent() should be eliminated..

How can this be done?

Comment: `Platform.exit()` to exit (src: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

Comment: ok thanks...now any help on starting a new game without closing the application?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar workflow in my project and I implemented the next way.[image]

Register a handler for OnCloseRequest:

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent -> appToBeClosed(stage, windowEvent));
```

Below methods to show a dialog with a question. Only if an user decided to stay you should consume the current window event and do something otherwise the application will be closed:

```
private void appToBeClosed(Stage notUsedStage, WindowEvent windowEvent) {
    if (hasNotSavedEvents()) {
        final Optional<ButtonType> userResponse = alertAboutNotSavedChangedEvents(
                "alert.changed.header", "alert.changed.content");
        if (userResponse.isPresent() && userResponse.get() == ButtonType.NO) {
            windowEvent.consume();
        }
    }
}

private Optional<ButtonType> alertAboutNotSavedChangedEvents(String headerResourceKey,
                                                             String contentResourceKey) {
    final Alert alert = new Alert();
    // TODO prepare alert as you wish...

    return alert.showAndWait();
}
```

I hope the main idea is clear and you will be able to adopt it to your project.
Let me know your questions.